# conn.connect(); Android Studio

Tags: android

Buenas, estoy creando mi primera aplicación android que es un trabajo para la universidad, llevo varios días intentando solucionar un problema de conexión con una url, ¿Podríais ayudarme?

Este es mi código:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_palabra_dificil_to_sinonimo);

    txtSinonimo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtSinonimo);

    //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myURL + URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString("Palabra"), "UTF-8"));InputStream is;
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Donde en myURL yo tengo puesto mi url y la excepción siempre me salta en `conn.connect();` ¿Podríais darme alguna solución?

Comment: que error marca en el LogCat???

Comment: Para que podemos saber como enfocar el problema, pon el logcat para ver el error y tu manifest.xml si declaras los permisos adecuados para tener conexión.

Answer (score 1):

Si el "error", ocurre cuando tratas de realizar la conexión,

```
 conn.connect();
```

la primera pregunta sería, ¿Definiste el permiso para conexión en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Si tienes definio el permiso, debes asegurarte que el url se forme correctamente, ya que el bundle podría no traer el string especificado y podrías estar tratando de cargar una URL incorrecta:

```
myURL += URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString("Palabra");

Log.i("Conexión", "el url es: " + myURL);  //revisa en el LogCat tu Url!.

URL url = new URL(myURL + URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString("Palabra"), "UTF-8"));
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he intentado poner: 

myURL += URLEncoder.encode(bundle.getString("Palabra"); pero no puedo me tacha el "encode". Asi que la he dejado como lo tenia.

Comment: Ademas he añadido la linea de código al manifest, y este queda asi:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
      ....
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PictogramaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PalabraDificilToSinonimoActivity"></activity>
    </application>

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta la otra respuesta, cuando vayas a realizar la conexión, recuerda que tienes que solicitar el permiso de Internet en el `Android Manifest` y también deberías comprobar que tu URL esté bien formada, aunque ese no es tu problema.
El problema que tienes es que estás lanzando una conexión en el hilo principal, y eso es lo que produce el error.
Para realizar tareas en un hilo secundario puedes utilizar un `AsyncTask`. En este enlace [puedes obtener más información sobre como utilizar esta clase](http://jarroba.com/asynctask-en-android/).

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar AsynkTask para que no se genere ningun conflicto con el hilo principal el de la aplicación , mira:

```
class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected <Type> doInBackground(Long... params) {
        URL ur_url = newURL(http://....) 
               // do the works on url.....
        return <tuped>result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // set the results in Ui

    }
}
```

> Y en tu actividad

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new       
                  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          new MyAsynTask().execute(null, null, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes realizar una conexión hacia internet en el hilo principal ya que bloquearías la aplicación, en las primeras versiones de Android esto era posible pero a partir de una versión se lanza una excepción al intentarlo y se fuerza el cierre de la aplicación.

Estaría bien saber que excepción te lanza ya que seguro que ahí te lo dice muy claramente. Como te dicen, además de los permisos tienes que ejecutarlo en un hilo que no sea el principal.